# How to transfer files from host OS to qemu running kernel only?

Tags: linux, kernel, qemu, cpu

I have used the instructions found in the readme.txt file from [here](https://gitlab.com/c-sky/buildroot/-/jobs/1251564514/artifacts/browse/output/images/) to run qemu-system-riscv64 for T-HEAD's C906 processor. QEMU successfully boots into the kernel, but there's not much functionality (as expected).

The only thing left is to transfer (binary) files that were cross-compiled from the host OS to the guest. But, there's no internet connection, no disk image (even if supplied one, it seems to be ignoring it) and doesn't have anything mounted.

I am intrested in running benchmarks in QEMU.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel itself cannot do anything aside from initializing hardware [devices] and creating RAM mappings (so you could use it from userspace). I'm not joking. What you're asking looks impossible.

Comment: If somehow an executable was moved (since for example there is wget available) wouldn't it run?
Is the only way to be "functional" to use an OS like Ubuntu or Debian with the desired kernel?

Comment: By the way, I have the impression that qemu-system-riscv64 is based on simulating a machine (-machine option) and not images. If I run this command https://wiki.debian.org/QEMU#Installation:~:text=qemu%2Dsystem%2Dx86_64%20%2Dhda%20debian.img%20%2Dcdrom%20debian%2Dtesting%2Damd64%2Dnetinst.iso%20%2Dboot%20d%20%2Dm%20512

with qemu-system-x86_64 it works, with qemu-system-riscv64 it just puts up the qemu monitor.

Comment: Edit: the downloaded iso was for amd64, and as it seems Debian doesn't support RISC-V. But the impression remains...